# Epson Stylus NX420 - Scanner fails, prints OK

Tags: drivers, scanner, epson

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.3. My Epson Stylus NX 420 Printer works OK w/ its driver, but I can't get the Scanner to work. It is connected to my network, and not directly plugged into my computer (I think this info is of importance). What can I do, to get the scanner to work as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1638597). Seems like the user was able to get things working.